# BadZipFile File is not a zip file

Tags: jupyter-notebook, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, embedding

In the following code, i get bad zip file error.

```
ctx = mx.gpu(0)
bert = BertEmbedding(ctx=ctx)
```

The output of the code is

```
Downloading C:\Users\USER\.mxnet\models\bert_12_768_12_book_corpus_wiki_en_uncased- 
75cc780f.zip from https://apache-mxnet.s3- 
accelerate.dualstack.amazonaws.com/gluon/models/bert_12_768_12_book_corpus_wiki_en_uncased- 
75cc780f.zip...
C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\gpu3\lib\site-packages\mxnet\gluon\utils.py:334: UserWarning: 
File C:\Users\USER\.mxnet\models\bert_12_768_12_book_corpus_wiki_en_uncased-75cc780f.zip 
exists in file system so the downloaded file is deleted
'File {} exists in file system so the downloaded file is deleted'.format(fname))
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-feea3bcdad25> in <module>
  1 ctx = mx.gpu(0)
----> 2 bert = BertEmbedding(ctx=ctx)

~\anaconda3\envs\gpu3\lib\zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
1196             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
1197         if not endrec:
-> 1198             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
1199         if self.debug > 1:
1200             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

The link of the code i am following is [this](https://github.com/hmohebbi/SentimentAnalysis/blob/master/main.ipynb)